# How to get a graph from the network?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Suppose we have the given network 'g1', which we get based on the set 'q1':

```
q1 = {{6545, 1044}, {6546, 1044}, {6536, 1044}, {6537, 1043}, {6529, 1044}, {6530, 1043}, {6528, 1044}, {6529, 1044}, {6528, 1044}, {6529, 1043}, {6527, 1044}, {6528, 1044}, {6522,1044}, {6523, 1043}, {6544, 1045}, {6545, 1044}, {6535,1045}, {6536, 1044}, {6526, 1045}, {6527, 1044}, {6521,1045}, {6522, 1044}, {6543, 1046}, {6544, 1045}, {6534,1046}, {6535, 1045}, {6525, 1046}, {6526, 1045}, {6521, 1046}, {6522, 1045}, {6520, 1046}, {6521, 1045}, {6517, 1046}, {6518, 1047}, {6542, 1047}, {6543, 1048}, {6542, 1047}, {6543, 1046}, {6535, 1047}, {6536, 1046}, {6534,1047}, {6535, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6534, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6534, 1046}, {6532, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6531, 1047}, {6532, 1047}, {6525, 1047}, {6526, 1048}, {6524, 1047}, {6525, 1047}, {6524, 1047}, {6525, 1046}, {6520, 1047}, {6521, 1046}, {6519, 1047}, {6520, 1047}, {6519, 1047}, {6520, 1046}, {6518, 1047}, {6519, 1047}, {6518, 1047}, {6518, 1048}, {6549, 1048}, {6550, 1049}, {6543, 1048}, {6544, 1049}, {6532, 1048}, {6533, 1049}, {6532, 1048}, {6533, 1047}, {6530, 1048}, {6531, 1047}, {6526, 1048}, {6527, 1049}, {6523, 1048}, {6524, 1047}, {6518, 1048}, {6518, 1049}, {6550, 1049}, {6551, 1050}, {6548, 1049}, {6549, 1048}, {6547, 1049}, {6548, 1049}, {6545, 1049}, {6546, 1050}, {6544, 1049}, {6545, 1049}, {6543, 1049}, {6544, 1049}, {6542, 1049}, {6543, 1049}, {6539, 1049}, {6540, 1050}, {6538, 1049}, {6539, 1049}, {6537, 1049}, {6538, 1049}, {6536, 1049}, {6537, 1049}, {6533, 1049}, {6534, 1050}, {6529, 1049}, {6530, 1048}, {6529, 1049}, {6529, 1050}, {6527, 1049}, {6528, 1050}, {6522, 1049}, {6523, 1048}, {6518, 1049}, {6519, 1050}, {6518, 1049}, {6518, 1050}, {6551, 1050}, {6551, 1051}, {6546, 1050}, {6547, 1049}, {6543, 1050}, {6544, 1049}, {6541, 1050}, {6542, 1049}, {6540, 1050}, {6541, 1050}, {6535, 1050}, {6536, 1049}, {6534, 1050}, {6535, 1050}, {6529, 1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6528, 1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6521, 1050}, {6522, 1049}, {6519, 1050}, {6520, 1051}, {6551, 1051}, {6551, 1052}, {6542, 1051}, {6543, 1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6529, 1052}, {6520, 1051}, {6521, 1052}, {6520, 1051}, {6521, 1050}, {6517, 1051}, {6518, 1050}, {6551, 1052}, {6552, 1052}, {6541, 1052}, {6542, 1051}, {6529,1052}, {6530, 1053}, {6521, 1052}, {6522, 1053}, {6540, 1053}, {6541, 1052}, {6538, 1053}, {6539, 1054}, {6531,1053}, {6532, 1054}, {6530, 1053}, {6531, 1054}, {6530, 1053}, {6531, 1053}, {6522, 1053}, {6522, 1054}, {6539, 1054}, {6540, 1053}, {6531, 1054}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 1055}, {6534, 1054}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 1056}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 1055}, {6521, 1055}, {6522, 1054}, {6533, 1056}, {6533, 1057}, {6520, 1056}, {6521, 1055}, {6534, 1057}, {6535, 1056}, {6533, 1057}, {6534, 1057}, {6519, 1057}, {6520, 1056}, {6518, 1058}, {6519, 1057}, {6517, 1059}, {6518, 1058}};
linesObjects = Map[Line@# &, Partition[q1, 2]];
g1 = Graphics[linesObjects, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Then we build the graph 'graph':

```
points = DeleteDuplicates[q1];
pointIndex = First /@ PositionIndex[points];
vertexCoordinates = AssociationMap[Reverse, pointIndex];
edges = BlockMap[Apply[UndirectedEdge], pointIndex /@ q1, 2];
graph = Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> Normal@vertexCoordinates]
```

[image]

Question: how to determine the set 'q1' from the 'graph' so as to reproduce the 'g1' network?

Example: Let 'graph1' be:

```
vtx[] := Table[i <-> RandomInteger[{0, i - 1}], {i, 1, 200}];
graph1 = Graph[vtx[], GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

How to get the set 'q2' (analogous to the set 'q1') from the graph 'graph1' so as to get the network 'g2' (analogous to the network 'g1')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to convert a graph into a graphics and get the lines representing all the edges? If so:

```
lines = Cases[Normal@Show[graph1], _Line, Infinity];
Graphics[lines]
```

creates and displays the lines. Note the use of Normal to convert from a GraphicsComplex to lines with the actual coordinates.

Or are you looking for the vertex coordinates for the endpoints of each edge?

For that, start with the coordinates of each vertex: (in version 12.1, use AnnotationValue instead of PropertyValue)

```
coords = Association[(# -> 
   PropertyValue[{graph1, #}, VertexCoordinates]) & /@ 
VertexList[graph1]];
```

then get the coordinates of the ends of each edge:

```
edgeCoordinates = Table[{coords[e[[1]]], coords[e[[2]]]}, {e, EdgeList[graph1]}];
```

Make a graph of lines of these edges

```
Graphics[Line /@ edgeCoordinates]
```

or for all segments in a single Line

```
Graphics[Line[edgeCoordinates]]
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks!